# Print special characters in SUNMI printer

Tags: escaping, special-characters, sunmi

i‘m trying to print **&** character in SUNMI printer. the printer stops printing when tjere is a **&**.

are there any poos. to escape this.

thanks for your help

i‘ve tried to use \ or to mask ist with / but this will not work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.